# Balance length of lines in Feynman diagram (feynmp)

Tags: feynman, feynmp

How can one make the Feynman diagram more symmetric? I want the 'photon/Z propagator' to be much shorter, and if possible, some more space in the right most part of my diagram, where the 'charginos' and 'Ws' decay.

I have tried to search for how `phantom` and `fmffreez` works, but I can't find out how it can help me.

```
% DIRECT PRODUCTION OF CHARGINO/NEUTRALINO
\unitlength=1mm
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{fmffile}{wz}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(90,30)
 % INCOMING + OUTGOING PARTICLES
  \fmfleft{d1,d2,e1,d3,d4,e2,d5,d6} % incoming particles, from below
  \fmfright{l1,n,X01,X02,q,qbar} % outgoing particles, from below
  \fmf{phantom}{d1,v0}
  \fmf{phantom}{d2,v0}
  \fmf{phantom}{d3,v0}
  \fmf{phantom}{d4,v0}
  \fmf{phantom}{d5,v0}
  \fmf{phantom}{d6,v0}
  \fmf{plain}{e1,v0} % incoming electron
  \fmf{plain}{e2,v0} % incoming positron
  \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma/Z$}{v0,v1}

  % DRAW STUFF
  \fmf{photon,label=\textcolor{red} {$\tilde{\chi}_1^{\pm}$},label.side=right,foreground=red}{v1,v2} % chargino, lower
  \fmf{photon,label=\textcolor{red}{$\tilde{\chi}_1^{\pm}$},label.side=left,foreground=red}{v1,v3}  % chargino, upper
  \fmf{photon,label=$W^{\pm}$,label.side=right,label.dist=0.3}{v2,v4} % lower W
  \fmf{photon,label=$W^{\pm}$,label.side=left,label.dist=0.2}{v3,v5} % upper W
  % decay of upper W
  \fmf{plain}{l1,v4,n}
  % decay of lower W
  \fmf{plain}{q,v5,qbar}
  % neutralinos in final state
  \fmf{photon,foreground=red}{v2,X01} % upper
  \fmf{photon,foreground=red}{v3,X02} % lower
  % additional lines for SUSY particles
  \fmf{plain,foreground=red}{v3,X02}
  \fmf{plain,foreground=red}{v1,v3}
  \fmf{plain,foreground=red}{v1,v2}
  \fmf{plain,foreground=red}{v2,X01}

% LABELLING
 \fmflabel{$e^+$}{e2} % incoming proton (first, from top)
 \fmflabel{$e^-$}{e1} % incoming proton (second)
 \fmflabel{$\bar{q}$}{qbar} % lepton in final state (first) in Z decay
 \fmflabel{$q$}{q} %  lepton in final state (second) in Z decay
 \fmflabel{$\nu$}{n} % neutralino in final state from W decay
 \fmflabel{$\ell^{\pm}$}{l1} % lepton in final state from W decay
 \fmflabel{\textcolor{red}{$\tilde{\chi}_1^0$}}{X01} % final state neutralino
 \fmflabel{\textcolor{red}{$\tilde{\chi}_1^0$}}{X02} % final state neutralino
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{center}
\hspace{1cm}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some tension to the long photon.

```
\fmf{photon,tension=3,label=$\gamma/Z$}{v0,v1}
```

looks about right on my system.

[image]

Each line you draw has a default tension of 1 and a unit weight.  Because you have so many extra lines on the right, they stretch the photon in the middle.  Adding tension to the photon balances the pull from the right.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed. I have never quite understood what the tension command does, but things got clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Although you mention using `feynmf/feynmp`, I'll provide an answer that uses another package: [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)).  Don't feel obliged to accept this answer if you need to use `feynmf/feynmp`.

Using the default underlying algorithm to place all the vertices, this can be done with:

```
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=z1 to z2] {
  %% Incoming electrons
  e1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)]
    -- [fermion] z1
    -- [fermion] e2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],

  %% gamma/Z propagator
  z1 -- [boson, edge label=\(\gamma / Z\)] z2,

  %% Supersymmetric particles
  {[edges={plain, boson}]
    z2 -- [edge label'=\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{\pm}\)] x1
       -- x3 [particle=\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{0}\)],
    z2 -- [edge label=\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{\pm}\)] x2
       -- x4 [particle=\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{0}\)],
  },
  %% We don't want the \chi to be too far apart
  x1 -- [draw=none] x2,

  %% W decaying hadronically
  x1 -- [boson, edge label'=\(W^{\pm}\)] w1,
  q11 [particle=\(\overline q\)] -- [fermion] w1 -- [fermion] q12 [particle=\(q\)],
  x2 -- [boson, edge label=\(W^{\pm}\)] w2,
  q21 [particle=\(\overline q\)] -- [fermion] w2 -- [fermion] q22 [particle=\(q\)],

  %% Finally, the algorithms wants to fan out the particles as much as possible,
  %% so to counter that we tie them together
  {[edges={draw=none}]
    q11 -- q12 -- x3 -- x4 -- q21 -- q22,
  },
};
```

[image: output 1]

which may suit you, but if you want finer control, then you'll have to use manual or relative placement of vertices.  The code gets a little more complicated, but nothing unmanageable:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    %% e e -> Z
    \vertex (z1);
    \vertex [above left=1.5cm and 1cm of z1] (e1) {\(e^{-}\)};
    \vertex [below left=1.5cm and 1cm of z1] (e2) {\(e^{+}\)};
    \vertex [right=2cm of z1] (z2);

    %% Z -> X X
    \vertex [above right=1cm of z2] (x1);
    \vertex [below right=1cm of z2] (x2);

    %% We now add the decays of the supersymmetric particles
    \vertex [right=2cm of x1] (x3) {\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{0}\)};
    \vertex [above right=1cm of x1] (w1);
    \vertex [right=1cm of w1] (q11) {\(\overline q\)};
    \vertex [above right=0.5cm and 1cm of w1] (q12) {\(q\)};
    %% Repeat with the second particle
    \vertex [right=2cm of x2] (x4) {\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{0}\)};
    \vertex [below right=1cm of x2] (w2);
    \vertex [right=1cm of w2] (q21) {\(\overline q\)};
    \vertex [below right=0.5cm and 1cm of w2] (q22) {\(q\)};

    %% Now connect the dots (literally)
    \diagram* {
      (e1) -- [fermion] (z1) -- [fermion] (e2),
      (z1) -- [boson, edge label=\(\gamma / Z\)] (z2),

      {[edges={plain, boson}]
        (z2) -- [edge label=\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{\pm}\)] (x1) -- (x3),
        (z2) -- [edge label'=\(\tilde \chi_{1}^{\pm}\)] (x2) -- (x4),
      },

      (x1) -- [boson, edge label=\(W^{\pm}\)] (w1),
      (x2) -- [boson, edge label'=\(W^{\pm}\)] (w2),

      (q11) -- [fermion] (w1) -- [fermion] (q12),
      (q21) -- [fermion] (w2) -- [fermion] (q22),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output 2]

For each of them, the code was enclosed in:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
%% <code above>
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing the problem, but I think I want to hold on to the feynmp package for now. I'll remember the tikz option for later:)